# How to log in without showing the screen by injecting React javascript code and going to the desired page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Frontend and React right now. Actually, I tried many things without posting here, but without success. What I want is I'm trying to send it to the login screen after going to another page in reactta and entering the relevant information on the login screen and without showing this login screen. My manager said that I can do this by injecting javascript on the react page. A blank page opens in the code I am currently writing. Without redirecting from any other page. My react code on the opened page is as follows.

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Col, Row, Typography } from 'antd';


// var url = 'https://192.168.6.146/login';

// export const openInNewTab = (url: string): void => {
//   const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
//   if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
// }

// export const onClickUrl = (url: string): (() => void) => () => openInNewTab(url)

// var theWindow = window.open('https://192.168.6.146/login'),
//     theScript = document.createElement('script');
// function injectThis() {
//     // The code you want to inject goes here
//     alert(document.body.innerHTML);
// }
// // Self executing function
// theScript.innerHTML = '(' + injectThis.toString() + '());';
// theWindow.onload = function () {
//     // Append the script to the new window's body.
//     // Only seems to work with `this`
//     this.document.body.appendChild(theScript);
// };

// function RedirectExample() {
//   React.useEffect(() => {
//     const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
//       window.location.replace('https://192.168.6.146/login');
//     }, 3000);

//     return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
//   }, []);

//   return <>Will redirect in 3 seconds...</>;
// }

// function RedirectReactRouterExample() {
//   return (
//     <Routes>
//       <Route path="/" element={<Index />} />
//       <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
//     </Routes>
//   );
// }

// function About() {
//   return <div>About</div>;
// }

// function Index() {
//   const navigate = useNavigate();

//   useEffect(() => {
//     setTimeout(() => {
//       navigate('/about', { replace: true });
//     }, 3000);
//   }, []);

//   return <div>Redirecting...</div>;
// }

// export class HoopWorks extends React.Component<any> {
//   render() {
//     return (
//       <Routes>
//       <Route path="https://192.168.6.146/login" element={<Index />} />
//       <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
//     </Routes>
//     );
//   }
// }
// export default HoopWorks;

// var session_url = 'https://192.168.6.146/hopsworks-api/api/auth/login';
// var querystring = require('querystring');

// axios.post(session_url, querystring.stringify({
//   username: 'admin', //gave the values directly for testing
//   password: 'admin'
// }), {
// headers: { 
// 'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
// "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
// 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
// }

//   }).then(function(response) {
//     console.log('Authenticated');
// }).catch(function(error) {
// console.log('Error on Authentication');
// });

export class HoopWorks extends React.Component<any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col span={8} offset={10} style={{marginTop:50}}>
          <Typography style={{fontSize:'50px'}}>{'HoopWorks-iFrame Page'}</Typography>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}
export default HoopWorks;
```

There are some codes that I have commented in between, I'm sorry, because I tried a lot of methods, they stayed like that. As I said, I just want to go to the https://192.168.6.146/login page and try to get the next page after automatically entering the user information. I would be very happy if you can help. Thank you from now.

Comment: I think you can use `useEffect` hook and invoke the login function in it.

Comment: Thank you I will definitely look into it @VictorL.